# How to clear dynamically created JavaScript and JQuery from log/buffer

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I clear dynamically create JavaScript and jQuery from the console / buffer?

When I click a reset button, I need to reload the script with out a full page reload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* 
     * Some Statements dynamically create JavaScript and jQuery
     */
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        var startDate, endDate, dateRange = [];

        //$("#turnoff1, #turnon1").datepicker("setDate", new Date());


        $("#turnoff1").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            beforeShow: function (input) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var buttonPane = $(input)
                        .datepicker("widget")
                        .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
                }, 1);
            },
            minDate: 0,
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            onClose: function (date) {
                startDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                var onday = document.getElementById('turnoff1').value;
                onday = new Date(onday);
                onday = (onday.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (onday.getDate() + 1) + '/' + onday.getFullYear();
                $("#turnon1").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    beforeShow: function (input) {
                        var b = $("#turnoff1").val();
                        if (b == "")
                            alert("Turn Off date please..!");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
                        }, 1);
                    },
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        endDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                        for (var d = new Date(startDate);
                            d <= new Date(endDate);
                            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                            dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d));
                        }
                    },
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
                });
                $('#turnon1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', onday);
            }
        });

        var i = $('#p_scents .DivContent').size() + 2;
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            if (i < 5) {
                var flag = false;
                if (i == 2) {
                    var preon = $('#turnon1').val();
                } else {
                    var z = "#turnon" + (i - 1);
                    var preon = $(z).val();
                }
                if (preon != "") {
                    $('#DivContent').append('<p>  Turn Off &nbsp;<input type="text" id="turnoff' + i + 
                    '" align="right" name="turnoff" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Turn On&nbsp;<input type="text" id="turnon'
                    + i + '" align="right" name="turnon" /> <input type="button" id="Rem" value=" X " </p> ');
                    var TOff = "turnoff" + i;
                    var TurnOff = "#" + TOff;
                    var TOn = "turnon" + i;
                    var TurnOn = "#" + TOn;
                    //alert(TOff);
                    $(TurnOff).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        beforeShow: function (input) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                var buttonPane = $(input)
                                    .datepicker("widget")
                                    .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
                            }, 1);
                        },
                        minDate: 0,
                        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                            var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
                            return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
                        },
                        onClose: function (date) {
                            startDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                            var onday = document.getElementById(TOff).value;
                            onday = new Date(onday);
                            onday = (onday.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (onday.getDate() + 1) + '/' + onday.getFullYear();
                            $(TurnOn).datepicker({
                                changeMonth: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                beforeShow: function (input) {
                                    var y = $(TurnOff).val();
                                    if (y == "")
                                        alert("Turn Off date please..!");
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
                                    }, 1);
                                },
                                onSelect: function (date, inst) {
                                    endDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                                    for (var d = new Date(startDate);
                                        d <= new Date(endDate);
                                        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                                        var COff = new Date(document.getElementById(TOff).value);
                                        var COn = new Date(document.getElementById(TOn).value);
                                        dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d));

                                        for (var k = 1; k < (i - 1); k++) {

                                            var Offin = "turnoff" + k;
                                            var Onin = "turnon" + k;
                                            var DOff1 = new Date(document.getElementById(Offin).value);
                                            var DOn1 = new Date(document.getElementById(Onin).value);

                                            if (((DOff1) >= (COff)) && ((DOff1) <= (COn))) {
                                                alert(" Between ate(s) already selected please check once.");
                                                $(TurnOff).val('');
                                                $(TurnOn).val('');
                                            }
                                            else if (((DOn1) >= (COff)) && ((DOn1) <= (COn))) {
                                                alert(k);
                                                alert("Between date(s) already selected please check once.");
                                                $(TurnOff).val('');
                                                $(TurnOn).val('');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                    var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
                                    return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
                                }
                            });

                            $(TurnOn).datepicker('option', 'minDate', onday);
                        }
                    });
                    i++;
                    person = "";
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select Date...!");
                }
            }
        });
        $('#Rem').click(function (event) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
        });
        $('#Res').click(function (event) {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                turndate = "#turnoff" + i + ", #turnon" + i;
                $(turndate).val('');
            }
            $("#DivContent").empty();
            i = 2;
        });
    });
```

My questions are

1. How can I clear dynamically create JavaScript and jQuery from the console/buffer with out a page reload..?
2. If between dates range are already selected, how can I avoid disabling newly selected dates? For the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows turn on

Please help me.

Comment: Once a script has run, it has run.  "Removing it" doesn't really do much.  If you could explain your problem, rather than what you think is a solution, then maybe we can help.

Comment: What do you exactly wants? Will you please elaborate your question.